# backgroundworker throws "An error occurred creating the form..."

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have main forms that has a button that opens a master-customer on datagrid. I use dataview for the purpose of filtering the data using dataview.rowfilter. 
The problem is, during the form load. It takes 5-6 seconds (the program is unresponsive during that time). What I'm trying to do is to load the data to the dataview on the background and  show it on the gridview on workercompleted.

it gave me this error: "An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it." --> on dowork

I read somewhere that i should use Invoke. But i don't know how to use it. 
here is my code:

```
Private Sub custcall_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TBfind.Enabled = False
    SetMyCustomFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    BWcustload.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub BWcustload_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BWcustload.DoWork

    mydataview = New DataView(datatablecust)
End Sub

 Private Sub BWcustload_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BWcustload.RunWorkerCompleted
    DGVcustomer.DataSource = mydataview
    TBfind.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the code to the event Form_Shown?

Also, have you tried putting the code in your DoWork section inside a SyncLock?

Try this:

```
SyncLock mydataview

    mydataview = New DataView(datatablecust)

End SyncLock
```

As for the STA model ... try adding this to your code and set the startup object to Sub Main()

```
   <STAThread()> _
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Dim mainForm As New custcall()
      Application.Run(mainForm)
   End Sub
```

EDITED:

As far as invoke is concerned.  ... that would definitely work, too ... but I don't know that it would have solved the STAThread issue.

To use invoke, first you have to declare a delegate sub in your form:

```
 Delegate Sub LoadDataCallback()
```

Declare a function to take care of the actual loading of the data:

```
Private Sub LoadData()
    mydataview = New DataView(datatablecust)
End Sub
```

Then, you would start a new thread in your Shown event (or Load event):

```
Dim mythread As New Thread(Sub()
                               Dim callLoad As New LoadDataCallBack(LoadData)

                               Me.Invoke(callLoad)
                           End Sub)

mythread.Start()
```

This gets around having to use SyncLock (although in some cases you may want to if it doesn't end up working correctly).

Don't forget to add Imports System.Threading to the top of your code file.

Comment: Hi nathan thanks for replying. using the synclock method it end up with "declaration expected" error on the snyclock part. When I use invoke method, it works but still 5-6 seccond loading time is expected.

Comment: Are you remembering to add a qualifying object to SyncLock?  Notice above that I typed "SyncLock mydataview"

It is possible to add another thread to monitor the progress of the load by checking the number of records imported on the control and reporting that to the form so the user knows that the data is still loading.  Not much can be done about the load time if you have a lot of data that needs to get imported, unfortunately.